# Getting java constraint annotations using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I would like to iterate some JAXB objects which are annotated with constraint validation annotations and retrieve the annotations programmatically through reflection . I have tried using the following code:

```
PropertyUtilsBean pub= new PropertyUtilsBean();
    PropertyDescriptor[] pds = pub.getPropertyDescriptors(object);

    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
        Class<?> propClazz = pd.getPropertyType();
        Annotation[] annotations = propClazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        for(Annotation a : annotations) {
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        }
```

However I can only get annotations define by the JAXB object, for example @XmlType, etc. Has anyone any suggestion please?

Comment: Are the annotations you want to retrieve available at runtime `@RETENETION(RUNTIME)` and defined at the class or at its fields or methods?

Comment: yes they are the typical bean validation constraint annotations provided by the JSR 303

Comment: Can you give more information or code?